# Q.reloadLookup() with new set of FilterField

Tags: serenity-platform

Hye, how can I use Q.reloadLookup() and at the same time, I want to change the FilterField (add more field and condition).

Comment: sounds like you are looking for a dynamic lookup based on your current state, regular lookups don't really do that, instead they are for a small amount of mostly static data that can be filtered on the page.`Q.reloadLookup() ` will force a refresh of the cache if data has changed since (and only if changed by your application) but you can't affect the loading filters. I have been using my own ajax based lookup component for that kind of thing.

Comment: More details would help to understand your problem statement